# Is there a function such as this:

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Can someone give me a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ where considering a point $P_0$ it is differentiable from all directions (meaning along a straight line), the function is continuous at this point, but not totally differentiable? Basically I'm asking if there is a case when I approach the point along a Jordan curve and the corresponding single variable function has a corner at this point. Because I'm guessing that if there is one then it is not differentiable but I'm not sure about that either.

Comment: Thank You for the modification! I really need to learn some Latex.